# woocommerce how to create brands tab

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I made a store where I have 2 categories, but now I want to make "brands tab" - brands list where user can click on any brand name to see items of only this brand (like on eBay, but simpler). I'm new to wordpress and woocommerce, so maybe you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce has this feature built in. Please check out the Woocommerce Shortcode site to see what you can do already.

But your shortcode will be:

```
[product_category category="appliances"]
```

Where "appliances" is the slug name of your category you want to filter the products by.

See the Woocommerce Shortcodes here http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Answer (score 0):

The brands plugin works well. Get it from WooThemes if you want support otherwise you can get it for cheap here: https://gplclub.org/product/woocommerce-brands/